# Need to extract data from a .Numbers file

Tags: mysql, csv, iwork, apple-numbers

I need to extract some images from about 1000 rows in a numbers file and I'm convinced there has to be a more efficient way to do it.

Ultimately, I'll be inserting all of this data into a MySQL db and I was hoping to use a CSV file but phpMyAdmin, for some reason, tells me there's an error when I upload it. I want to extract all of the non-text data but I'd like not to manually go through each row and pull the images. Does anyone know of a more efficient way to do this?

Comment: We're unlikely to be able to help you without seeing more context. Could you post your actual code here and [describe what you've tried](http://whathaveyoutried.com)? Be sure also to check the [question checklist](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/156810/stack-overflow-question-checklist). Thanks!